# Calculate total value inline form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new with bootstrap coding. I have a simple question, but I cannot find the answer.

This is what I need: I have weight of a single item, the number of units I need to calculate total weight.

Can somebody help me please?

```
<div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Unit Weight:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uweight" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Units:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="units" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Total:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" >
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one way to do  http://jsfiddle.net/ny74j496/1/

Comment: Hi Ottavio,Thank you much for prompt respond. Can this be done with out [calculate] button? After user go to nest field total calculates automatically?

Comment: you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ny74j496/4/

Comment: Great all work fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome, added an answer below so you can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to pull in the value of your inputs with their IDs then perform your calculations. You just have to assign a variable to each input ID and the for the calculation, then output to `#total`.

*I've changed your input type to `number` from `text` also.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.form-control', function() {
    var yourWeight, yourUnits, yourTotal;
    yourWeight = $(' #uweight ').val();
    yourUnits = $(' #units ').val();
    yourTotal = (parseFloat(yourWeight)) * (parseFloat(yourUnits));
    $(' #total ').val(yourTotal.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form name="calcForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Unit Weight:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="uweight" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
          <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Units:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="units" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
          <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Total:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total" disabled/>
          <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unnecessarily overkill solution and above of that OP wants to calculate the input values on the fly without any button to calculate, check OP comment below question, Sidenote: great effort :)

Comment: Yes, the last code is much better only one thins I had to change, so after form filled out I could send it correctly. id="total" disabled should be changed to readonly.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Not sure if  I have start new thread for another question regarding same form? I have total of 24 fields in the form. After submitting it I'm receiving email with all the information except from fields with drop down selection. Why this happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Best thing to do is ask a new question and tag it with whatever your using (PHP/Ruby, etc) to process the form and the code for the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add `calculate` class to each input later bind with [jQuery keyup function](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), when the user releases the keys, calculation can be done on the fly and sum will be output to `#total`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Calculate both inputs value on the fly
    $('.calculate').keyup(function () {
        var Tot = parseFloat($('#units').val()) + parseFloat($('#uweight').val());
        $('#total').val(Tot);
    });

    //Clear both inputs first time when user focus on each inputs and clear value 00
    $('.calculate').focus(function (event) {
        $(this).val("").unbind(event);
    });

    //Remove this it's just for example purpose
    $('.calculate').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Unit Weight:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" id="uweight" required value="00">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Units:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" id="units" required value="00">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Total:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" readonly>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 control-group form-group" id="errmsg"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny74j496/4/)

Comment: You understand my answer was there before the OPs comment was posted? Your answer does not allow for the use of decimal notation (ei 1.5) (and yes, I did see the comment to remove, but it's of little value in general) for a weight and I don't believe weight + units = total weight, it should be weight MULTIPLIED (*) by units.

Comment: @vanburen, can answer your comment but it will start new debate so, you are right and your answer is much better then mine and you can have the winner's cup, cheers